# How do I force an app to reload when opened

Tags: firefox-os

I'm working on a todo app that uses indexedDB. Everything is working fine on my Flame phone. One exception: when I open the app a day later to check my tasks, it doesn't reload the database. Yesterday's items still appear as today's items, etc. I have to hold the home button, quit the app and the start it again. I used the code below to force reloads, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<meta http-equiv = "pragma" content = "no-cache">
<meta http-equiv = "cache-control" content = "no-cache">
```

Comment: When are reading the DB?  Can you use a visibility change event to do the read?

Comment: I open and read the DB at the very beginning (window.onload). I close the DB at the end (window.onclose). Not sure I understand what you mean by visibility change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) event to listen when your app becomes active.

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (!document.hidden) {
    // reload
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about that event listener. I'll put it in. Will know tomorrow it it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reload, you need to planify a regular reload.
I would use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) which reload the page or reload your base.

```
// Initial load
loadInterface();

function loadInterface() {
  // You load your tasks
  // You change your interface
  // ...

  // Next reload : in 60m*60s = 1h
  window.setTimeout(loadInterface, 3600000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. I don't need an hourly reload. The moment I add a new task, it reloads. It's just when I start the app on a new day, it still thinks it's the previous day. Maybe I'll increase the interval to 86400000.